# notification system in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications, messaging

I am beginner in ruby on rails. I am building a forum application. In addition to post and comments on posts, I want the private messaging system in the application. The message should be sent to the desired user("only that user can see the message"). For that I generated a model **Notification** having *message* as a column. 
**Notification Model**

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

**Notification Migration**

```
class CreateNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :notifications do |t|
      t.text :message  
      t.timestamps null: false    
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true    
    end   
  end
end
```

**Notification Controller**

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController


    def index
        @notifications = Notification.all.order("created_at DESC")

    end

    def new
        @notification = Notification.new
    end

    def create
        @notification = Notification.new notification_params
        if @notification.save
            redirect_to(:controller => "posts", :action => "index")
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    private

    def notification_params
        params.require(:notification).permit(:message, :user_id)
    end

end
```

**Notification#new** view

```
<%= form_for(:notification, :url => {:action => "create"}) do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field(:message, :placeholder => "Enter your message") %>
    <%= f.hidden_field(:user_id, :value => session[:user_id]) %>
    <%= f.submit("send message") %>

<% end %>
```

How can I send the target user attribute in the form? or is there a different way for messaging system? 
Please help me. I appreciate your answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think if you have `t.references :user` sets the `user_id`, so you set that twice in your migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store a reference to the recipient in the notification.

`t.integer :recipient_id`

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Also don't set the user_id in the form, set it in the controller.
( Otherwise anybody could create a notification for anybody else, just by sending wrong input ).

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
     @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
     @notification = @user.notifications.new notification_params
     # ...
  end
end
```

Not a complete solution, but will point you to the right direction.

Comment: from where recipient came from(belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'). And what class_name: 'User' does? I am very beginner in rails. Can you explain me clearly?

Comment: `recipient_id` is just a column name, to store the id of the recipient. I made it up, you can name it how you like. But you  need a reference to the user who will get the notification. Rails can figure out the class name from the belongs_to :user, but :recipient is not a different class, you want that to reference other users, that's why you need to tell rails in this case.

Comment: and in notification model, you used  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'. But we didn't declare the model recipient. How can we use the assosiation. Sorry If this is a silly qustion. I am very beginner in rails.

Comment: You could set the original `belongs_to :user` like `belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id` Its your choice. Check the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Then you would have the method `creator` on your Notification instances instead of user.

Comment: Ok, now I got some clarity. I will try this and let you know